# Resent mysql values at certain time

Tags: php, mysql, flags

I have a database with a table and some columns.  One of these columns is flags (similar to SO) where users can flag comments.  I would like to give each user 5 flags per day.  So if a user uses 2 flags in a 24 hour period, the flags should reset to 5 at the end of the 24 hours.  I really have no idea how to do this.  Is there a special mysql function?

PHP:

```
$query=mysql_query("UPDATE users SET flags='5' WHERE userID='$user'");
```

how would i get this to repeat every 24 hours? (if this is the right solution)

Comment: By 24h do you mean from 0 to 24 or say the user subscribe at 6am, 24h are 6 am - 6am?

Comment: Daily cron job that runs the query "UPDATE mytable SET flags = 5"?

Comment: Why don't you count user's flags for today _on demand_?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way is probably to set up an automated task (possibly using [cron](http://unixgeeks.org/security/newbie/unix/cron-1.html)) that runs a query to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Make a script and add to [cron job](http://www.sitepoint.com/introducing-cron/). It will automatically update all on specified time of day.

Cron is very simply a Linux module that allows you to run commands at predetermined times or intervals. In Windows, it’s called Scheduled Tasks. The name Cron is in fact derived from the same word from which we get the word chronology, which means order of time.

Using Cron, a developer can automate such tasks as mailing ezines that might be better sent during an off-hour, automatically updating stats, or the regeneration of static pages from dynamic sources. Systems administrators and Web hosts might want to generate quota reports on their clients, complete automatic credit card billing, or similar tasks. Cron has something for everyone!

Answer (score 0):

You can use MySQL [Event Scheduler](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events.html) and define an event to let it update every interval you want.